# How to save id using groovy from response?

Tags: groovy, soapui

in soapui my project is :

```
Project
   |__Datasource
   |__request
   |__groovy_code
   |__DatasourceLoop
```

- My Datasource contains 100 lines, each one is a request with different parameters.
- My groovy_code save the id from the response of the request.

When i run my project, it executes 100 requests without errors.
groovy_code save only the first id.

What i want is to save id for each request, so 100 ids in different variables at project level

Here is my groovy_code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = context.expand( '${login#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://elsian/ns/20110518\'; //ns1:login_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response)
log.info result.data.id
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("token_id", result.data.id)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use SOAPUI PRO and I don't have access to `datasource testStep` or even `datasource loop`.

However based on the project structure you're showing I suppose that for each time `datasource loop` founds a element in `datasource` it sends the flow to request step so request and groovy steps are executed on each iteration; due to this I think that the problem is that your groovy code is overriding each time the same property with a new value.

Then to solve this you can try adding some variable suffix to your property name to avoid override each time the property value. For example you can add to `token_id` string a counter, some uuid, current ms etc.

For example you can use a counter as a suffix. To keep the counter value you've to save it in the `context` variable, this way this property are shared between your tests inside the current execution:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// create a suffix function to generate
// the suffixs for your property names based on a count
def getSuffixNameProperty = {
    // check if already exists 
    if(context['count']){
        // if exists simply add 1
        context['count']++
    }else{
        // if not exists initialize the counter
        context['count'] = 1
    }
    return context['count']
}

def propertyName = "token_id" + getSuffixNameProperty();

def response = context.expand( '${login#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://elsian/ns/20110518\'; //ns1:login_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue(propertyName, result.data.id)
```